# CHECK_NRPE: (ssl_err != 5) Error - Could not complete SSL handshake with 192.168.X.X

Tags: linux, nagios

I'm using two debian machines one is a Nagios server and the other is Remote Linux host as a test for Nagios server !

CHECK_NRPE: (ssl_err != 5) Error - Could not complete SSL handshake with 192.168.X.X

I get this message on Nagios server when he tried to contact the Remote one it can ping I can use SSH root@ip but I don't know how to solve the problem ?

I really need your help

Comment: Reason is that you have SSL enabled in remote NRPE but you have some problem with certificates. Are they setup correctly?

Comment: Certificate or possibly versions if I remember correctly from my read through.  I had to upgrade the  nrpe host, generate a cert on client and place on host (other circumstances than in this question)